# Laravel php artisan migrate errors on empty database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-artisan

Weird things are happening. Been trying to run migrations with `php artisan migrate` but get the following error about a missing table (that is supposed to be created and populated by migrations).

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app.portals' doesn't exist in /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(80): PDO->prepare('select * from `...', Array)
#1 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(326): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->prepare('select * from `...')
#2 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(657): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('select * from `...', Array)
#3 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel in /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app.portals' doesn't exist in /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(80): PDO->prepare('select * from `...', Array)
#1 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(326): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->prepare('select * from `...')
#2 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(657): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('select * from `...', Array)
#3 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel in /home/daniel/Programming/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
```

Laravel Version: 5.5.*

PHP Version: 7.1

Backstory:

I decided to work on a new local database installation instead of always relying on a remote one. Then I found artisan doesn't work anymore.

Attempts:

Every artisan command I could get my hands on, but none of them worked because even `php artisan --help` threw the error above...

I also tried cloning the repo as a fresh start, then checking out the branch I'm working on, and running `php artisan migrate` with the same error.

Migrations:

I can't post all of them, but there is one migration that builds the missing table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePortalLinks extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('portal_viewer_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('viewer_user_id');
            $table->integer('portal_id');
        });

        Schema::create('admin_user_portal', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('admin_user_id');
            $table->integer('portal_id');
        });

        Schema::create('portals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('identifier');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('viewer_user_portal');
        Schema::dropIfExists('portal_admins');
        Schema::dropIfExists('portals');
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a migration that is trying to modify a table that doesn't exist yet.  It's hard to diagnose without seeing the migrations...can you post those?

Comment: Have you tried 'php artisan migrate:refresh'?

Comment: Show your migration. When you started working on the local database, did you migrate the remote database exactly?

Comment: @ka_lin Yup, and it gave me the same error :(

Comment: @aynber I started working on the local database after a migration that was run on the develop db caused my local branch to break. I thought running `php migrate:refresh` would simply build the db from the ground up.

Comment: Check your database. Do `portals`, `viewer_user_portal`, and `portal_admins` exist? If none do, remove the migration from the migrations table and rerun your migrations. If only some do, comment out the ones that exist, remove the migration from the migrations table and rerun your migrations. If all three exist... make sure it's using the right database?

Comment: @aynber Don't have a migrations table on the db. Is that maybe causing problems?

Comment: @aynber I actually have no tables at all. Do I have to add them myself?

Comment: Well, that is a problem. Try `php artisan migrate:install`, then rerun your migrations. Check the naming scheme of the files, and make sure that the date for the table creation comes before the date of the column additions.

Comment: @aynber The same error gets thrown if I run `php artisan migrate:install`. :( I noticed that my PortalService is being instantiated when I run `php artisan`... Super weird.

Comment: @aynber So it turns out one of my service providers was querying the DB in its constructor, thereby causing `php artisan` to fail completely, before any migrations could run. Ran the commands `php artisan migrate:install`, followed by `php artisan migrate:fresh` which populated my db with all tables!

Comment: Try to just use `php artisan migrate:refresh` to rollback all your database and migrate it again. You won't have any problem with this as long as your database connection is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cause of Error:

Error was caused by a Laravel service provider that had a database query in its constructor.

It turns out - I didn't know about this - that Laravel service providers get instantiated when running artisan.

Solution:

Once I put some validation in my service provider to stop the query from happening on artisan commands, running `php artisan migrate:install`, `php artisan migrate:fresh`, and `php artisan migrate --seed` populated by database with all the necessary tables and records.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying refresh.

you should try php artisan migrate:**fresh**

THe down command will not work because there is nothing to delete.

When u run the refresh command laravel will first try to roll back everything using the down functions.then it will rebuild everything. On the server u never had a problem because those tables were there. BUt here on a new installation, the whole thing cant be rolled back. There is nothing to roll back.

Comment: Didn't work. I keep getting this error when running anything to do with `php artisan`, unfortunately :(

Comment: The error says `'select * from `...'` Array which seems to suggest that some migration somewhere is assuming some table already exists somewhere.
More details on the migration?
One more thing that comes to my mind is to run migrations one table at a time. SO that you can pin down exactly where the problem is. by say editing the code 

to 

`...   public function up(){        Schema::create('portal_viewer_user',function (Blueprint $table) {            $table->integer('viewer_user_id');            $table->integer('portal_id');        });); }`

Comment: Hm... Didn't seem to work. I noticed, however, that my PortalService is being instantiated when I run `php artisan`... I'm guessing this shouldn't happen?

Comment: So my PortalService had a db query in its constructor, which failed every time I ran the `php artisan` command. I added a bit of validation to prevent the query from happening in the CLI, which fixed the error on my post! I then ran `php artisan migrate:install` and `php artisan migrate:fresh`, which created all the tables in my db.